# JS Prototype error "Prototype is not defined"

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am new to JS, I write below code, but I got the error "Prototype is not defined".

```
var proto = {
    describe: function () {
        return 'name: ' + this.name;
    }
};

var obj = {                
    [[Prototype]]: proto, //error in this line
    name:'obj'
};

console.log(proto.describe());
console.log(obj.describe());
```

Comment: [[prototype]] is an internal property, not a valid name for a key. You want to use `Object.create`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[Prototype]]` is only specification-speech for an internal property (the link in the prototype chain). To link `obj` to `proto` through the prototype chain, you can use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create):

```
   var obj = Object.create(proto);
   obj.name = 'obj';
```

Or [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) in ES6/ES2015:

```
    var obj = {                
        name:'obj'
    };

    Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, proto);
```

Alternatively, there is the legacy property [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), which is not necessarily recommended though:

```
    var obj = {                
        __proto__: proto,
        name:'obj'
    };
```

Comment: Don't use `__proto__`. It's been officially deprecated with ES6. Use `Object.setPrototypeOf` instead if you have to.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that, Allen Wirfs-Brock even "recommended" using it: https://twitter.com/awbjs/status/730789464021159938. `Object.setPrototypeOf`modifies the prototype of a live object, so there will be a performance hit. `__proto__` in the object literal should have avoided that. Looks like there is no clean method to link object literals anymore…

Comment: If `Object.setPrototypeOf` is used immediately after the object creation, it shouldn't have a performance hit.